# Execute multiple command lines with output

Tags: c#, cmd, output

I want to perform some command lines to display the result after each input.

```
    Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    info.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo = info;
    p.Start();
    using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
    {
        if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("ftp");
            //output
            sw.WriteLine("open ftp.server.com");
            //output
            sw.WriteLine("username");
            //output
            sw.WriteLine("password");
            //output
        }
    }
```

Help me to understand how to make the output result after each `sw.WriteLine(...)`?

#### Updated

It is not working with ftp. Why?

Initialization:

```
Test test = new Test();
test.start();
Console.ReadKey();
```

Class `Test`:

```
class Test
    {    
        static StringBuilder StdOutput = new StringBuilder();
        Process p = null;
        Queue<string> cmdQueue = new Queue<string>();

        public void start(){

            cmdQueue = new Queue<string>();
            cmdQueue.Enqueue("cd c:\\");
            cmdQueue.Enqueue("dir");

            cmdQueue.Enqueue("ftp");
            cmdQueue.Enqueue("open us1.hostedftp.com");
            cmdQueue.Enqueue("z3r9@ya.ru");
            cmdQueue.Enqueue("123456");
            cmdQueue.Enqueue("dir");
            setupProcess();
            startProcess();    
        }

        private void setupProcess()
        {
            p = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.FileName = "cmd";
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;

            p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputDataHandler);

            StdOutput = new StringBuilder();

            p.StartInfo = info;
        }

        private async void startProcess()
        {
            p.Start();    
            p.BeginOutputReadLine();                    

            using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
            {

                if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    while (cmdQueue.Count > 0)
                    { 
                            string cmd = cmdQueue.Dequeue();

                            if (cmd != null & cmd != "")
                            {
                                await sw.WriteLineAsync(cmd);

                                Thread.Sleep(100);

                                //System.Console.WriteLine(StdOutput);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }  
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(StdOutput);    
                }                       
                p.WaitForExit();                    
            }
        }

        private static void OutputDataHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
            {
                StdOutput.Append(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);    
                //System.Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);    
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are actually asking about how to catch **outputs** from **all** the commands you want to have executed in the (one) process.

Here is a version of a solution I came up with a long time ago, when I was a rookie here..

The trick is to collect the output as is comes along by **listening** to events the `Process` will trigger whenever output gets created: `OutputDataReceived` and `ErrorDataReceived`. We need to run things `async` for this to work, so it will look **a little more complicated** than the usual examples, which only have **one** process executing **one** command..:

First a few variables:

```
    Queue<string> cmdQueue = new Queue<string>();
    static StringBuilder StdOutput = new StringBuilder();
    static StringBuilder ErrOutput = new StringBuilder();

    Process p = null;
    Task processTask = null;
    bool processIsRunning = false;
```

Here is a button click event that starts processing all commands from a multiline `TextBox`. Output gets collected in the two `StringBuilders`; when the queue is empty, I wait a little longer..:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmdQueue = new Queue<string>(tb_commands.Lines.ToList());

    setupProcess();
    startProcessTask();

    while (cmdQueue.Count > 0) Thread.Sleep(100);
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    tb_out.AppendText(StdOutput + "\r\n" + ErrOutput + "\r\n");
}
```

Here is the routine that set up the `Process`. Here we **register two events** that will notify us when there are lines in the output streams..:

```
private void setupProcess()
{
    p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
    info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    info.RedirectStandardError = true;
    info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    info.UseShellExecute = false;

    p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputDataHandler);
    p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ErrorDataHandler);
    StdOutput = new StringBuilder();
    ErrOutput = new StringBuilder();
    p.StartInfo = info;
}
```

After the setup we can start a `Task` that will start our `Process` **asynchonously**..:

```
private void startProcessTask()
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => startProcess());
    processTask = task;
}
```

..and finally here is the async method that after starting the `Process` and beginning with the asynchronous read operations on the redirected streams,  keeps feeding it all lines from the command queue.

```
private async void startProcess()
{
    try { p.Start(); processIsRunning = true; } catch
    {
        ErrOutput.Append("\r\nError starting cmd process.");
        processIsRunning = false;
    }

    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    p.BeginErrorReadLine();

    using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
    {

        if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    string cmd = cmdQueue.Dequeue();
                    if (cmd != null & cmd != "") await sw.WriteLineAsync(cmd);
                } catch { }
            } while (processIsRunning);
        try { p.WaitForExit(); } catch { ErrOutput.Append("WaitForExit Error.\r\n"); }
    }
}
```

The last pieces are the two events we have registered for reading the output from the two streams and adding them to the `StringBuilders`:

```
private static void OutputDataHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
    {  
        StdOutput.Append(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
    }
}

private static void ErrorDataHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
    {  
        ErrOutput.Append(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
    }
}
```

Note that this works fine for all sorts of commands you can feed into the process, **including FTP**. Here I change my codepage, show the images I have before, log in to an FTP server, call up the help page, cd and dir, download an image, close the connection and check the images I have now..:

[image]

**One Caveat**: There must be something wrong in the way I wrote this, as VS keeps complaining about a `System.InvalidOperationException` and the exe file hogs ~10% cpu. Helping me out would be very much appreciated..

Comment: Well, as you can see it __is__ working here. Note that only output that is actually sent to stdout __can__ be captured!

Comment: I updated the main post. I added an example.The ftp command is not working. Why? Please tell me.

Comment: Hm. I had no problems with ftp. (I'm on win8.1 and logged in with admin rights)) I guess you can feed your very same commands into a cmd window manually?

Comment: Hi, I have tested your version now and at least in the WinForms program I have it works just fine. The __only__ changes were: using my ftp test commands, removing the `Console.ReadKey();` and adding a `System.Console.WriteLine( Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data); ` to the `OutputDataHandler` to show the output.. - I'll have to look into this again somt time, as your version somehow doesn't show the issues mine did. However your problems with ftp are probably coming from somewhere else..

Comment: The answer on russian: http://www.sql.ru/forum/1161247-a/ftp-cherez-komandnuu-stroku-v-c